# How to change item price in cart by input field?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In cart.php I have an input where user can input your own price

```
    <input type="number" id="customPrice">
    <div data-id="<?php echo $product_id ?>" id="updateCart">Update</div>
```

And I have a js function for make ajax request with product id and new price data

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        let customPrice = document.getElementById('customPrice');
        let price = customPrice.value;

        let updateCart = document.getElementById('updateCart');
        let id = updateCart.dataset.id


        updateCart.addEventListener('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                data: {action: "add_custom_price", id: id, price: 10},
                type: "POST",
                success(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        console.log(data)
                    }
                    $("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

In my functions.php i have

```
    function add_custom_price($cart)
{
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return;

    if (did_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals') >= 2)
        return;

    if (isset($_POST['price']) && $_POST['id']) {
        $price = intval($_POST['price']);
//        $id = intval($_POST['id']);

        foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($price);
        }
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_add_custom_price', 'add_custom_price');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_custom_price', 'add_custom_price');
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price', 1000, 1);
```

But it don't work. I have 500 error

Where is my mistake? Or how i can do it or another way? Any suggestion please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the product, then affect the price, then save

```
 function add_custom_price($cart) {
     if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX'))
         return;

     if (did_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals') >= 2)
         return;

     if (isset($_POST['price']) && $_POST['id']) {
         $price = intval($_POST['price']);
         $id = intval($_POST['id']);

         // Get product
         $product = wc_get_product($id);
         $product->set_regular_price($price);
         $product->save();
         // delete the relevant product transient
         wc_delete_product_transients( $id );
     }
 }
```

Comment: 500 is missing but the price does not change

Comment: I updated my answer. i think it's the cached amount you're seeing. Try this

Comment: are you SURE the $id is the product id?

Comment: also, do some troubleshooting here. I am feeling my way around in the dark. 'Still not working' means nothing, whereas 'I tried a die(print_r($product)) and got this as the respone...' is meaningful

Comment: I found a solution I just replace set_price on  set_regular_price($price), and it works even without deleting the relevant product transient, thank you for your help!

Comment: Awesome. I updated my answer, would you accept it as the answer? Thanks. I left the transient line in there as it's recommended by woocommerce.